# I came up with the psmouse elantech error. Let me know how to resolve this

Tags: elantech

psmouse serio1: elantech: elantech_send_cmd querry 0x02 failed /psmouse serio1: failed to query capabilities

I'm unable to login to my system. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems like a recent issue... also need to know how to solve it.